# TypeScript add properties to and change the type of a deeply nested property

Tags: typescript, types

I have an auto generated type by graphql codegen which is as follows

```
type GetAppsAndExtensionsQuery = {
    applications: Array<{
        id: number;
        name: string;
        extensions: Array<{
            extension: {
                id: number;
                name: string;
            };
        }>;
        appRelationships: Array<{
            softwareId: number;
        }>;
        appPacks: Array<{
            applications: string;
        }>;
    }>;
}
```

I wanted to convert the property `appRelationships` to the type `Set<number>` as I'm transforming the data before using it. So I found a type converter which is defined as such

```
export type Replace<T, A, B> = T extends object ? { [key in keyof T]: key extends A ? B : Replace<T[key], A, B> } : T;
```

This is how I'm converting the type `appRelationships` from type `Array` to type `Set<number>`

```
type IntermediateApplicationsType = Replace<
    GetAppsAndExtensionsQuery['applications'][0],
    'appRelationships',
    Set<number>
>;
```

I want to add two more propreties to the `applications` property of `GetAppsAndExtensionsQuery` so this is what I do. I just replace the `applications` property in `GetAppsAndExtensionsQuery` with the newly created type that I want `applications` to be.

I also replace the property `appPacks` with the original type's `appPacks` property as `appPacks` also has a property called `applications` which would also get replaced so I just re-replace it. It feels like a hack, but that's the best solution I could come up with.

```
export type FinalType = Replace<
    Replace<
        GetAppsAndExtensionsQuery,
        'applications',
        (IntermediateApplicationsType & {
            selectableExtensionIds: Set<number>;
            allAppsDescendants: Set<number>;
        })[]
    >,
    'appPacks',
    GetAppsAndExtensionsQuery['appPacks']
>;
```

Now the problem is that the property `allAppsDescendants` is not longer of type `Set<number>` for some reason and I can't figure out why.

When I do the following and check the type of `allAppsDescendants` it's something weird

```
const test: FinalType = {} as FinalType;
test.applications[0].allAppsDescendants

// type of allAppsDescendants is

(property) allAppsDescendants: {
    add: {};
    clear: {};
    delete: {};
    forEach: {};
    has: {};
    readonly size: number;
    entries: {};
    keys: {};
    values: {};
    [Symbol.iterator]: {};
    readonly [Symbol.toStringTag]: string;
}
```

Instead of being of type `Set<number>`, it's got all the properties that the type `Set` has.

`selectableExtensionIds` on the other hand has the correct type

```
const hh: AppAndExtensionsComponentProp;
hh.applications[0].selectableExtensionIds

// type of selectableExtensionIds

(property) selectableExtensionIds: Set<number>
```

Is there a way to make the type that I want? I couldn't find many resources on this topic

Comment: Is the problem that you need a "deep" replacer type? It seems that the replacer type you have used will only work for one level of nesting which will be very annoying to work with.

Comment: The replacer I'm using is a deep one. It's recursive and replaces properties on every level. That's why I had to replace `appPacks` because the `applications` field in `appPacks` was also being replaced in the `FinalType`